# Update specific column based on other column value

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to update in `Table 2` two columns `L1`, `L2` based on the `Lcolumn` value in `Table 1`. If in Table 1 `Lcolumn = "L1"` then in Table 2 the `L1` column has to be updated, otherwhise the `L2` column.

**Table 1**

| fnr | gnr | wnr | Lcolumn | Lcode |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 0 | 49 | L1 | 19 |
| 3 | 0 | 49 | L2 | 29 |
| 3 | 0 | 50 | L1 | 20 |
| 3 | 0 | 50 | L2 | 7 |
| 3 | 0 | 51 | L1 | NULL |

**Table 2**

| fnr | gnr | wnr | L1 | L2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 0 | 49 | NULL | NULL |
| 3 | 0 | 50 | NULL | NULL |
| 3 | 0 | 51 | NULL | NULL |

In the example there are four `Lcodes`, for 50 - L1 and L2 and 51 - L1 and L2

When I run two individual queries for L1 and L2 ( [fiddle 1](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/diug6jeb1oabRZMus3MRko/1) )

```sql
UPDATE table2 B
    LEFT JOIN table1 A
    ON( A.fnr = B.fnr AND A.gnr = B.gnr AND A.wnr = B.wnr AND A.Lcolumn = "L1" )
    SET 
        B.L1= A.Lcode 
    WHERE A.Lcode IS NOT NULL
```

(and the same for L2) the updates give the desired result: in Table 2 for wnr 50 and 51 both L1 and L2 are filled with the corresponding Lcodes.

**Table 2 - desired result**

| fnr | gnr | wnr | L1 | L2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 0 | 49 | 19 | 29 |
| 3 | 0 | 50 | 20 | 7 |
| 3 | 0 | 51 | NULL | NULL |

When however I combine the two queries ( [fiddle 2](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mDP7EzRZQrk8Vhn8ya7XBx/1) )

```sql
UPDATE table2 B
  LEFT JOIN table1 A
  ON( A.fnr = B.fnr AND A.gnr = B.gnr AND A.wnr = B.wnr )
SET 
  B.L1= IF( A.Lcolumn = "L1" , A.Lcode , B.L1 ), 
  B.L2= IF( A.Lcolumn = "L2" , A.Lcode , B.L2 )
WHERE A.Lcode IS NOT NULL
```

I expected the same result, but in reality per `wnr` **only one** of the L-columns is updated, the other one stays NULL.

I can live with 2 queries, it's more the WHY that's bothering me because there are two results for every `wnr` from the JOIN ( [fiddle 3](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gN4ntYb1PbCB9san1oUp6T/1) ), each with it's own `Lcolumn`. So why is the query skipping rows (or resetting values?). And if - as a bonus - someone can solve the problem, that would be great.

Comment: Ermm, and if someone can tell me why all the tables are unformatted altough they looked nice in the preview???

Comment: you need a blank line before tables ;)

Comment: @AymDev Ah, thanks. Might be handy to include that in the formatting tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Columns L1 and L2 are independent, source data lines for them are independent, so you must use independent source table copies:

```sql
UPDATE table2 t2
LEFT JOIN table1 t1L1 USING (fnr, gnr, wnr)
LEFT JOIN table1 t1L2 USING (fnr, gnr, wnr)
SET t2.L1 = COALESCE(t1L1.Lcode, t2.L1),
    t2.L2 = COALESCE(t1L2.Lcode, t2.L2)
WHERE t1L1.Lcolumn = 'L1'
  AND t1L2.Lcolumn = 'L2';
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/diug6jeb1oabRZMus3MRko/2

Comment: Is it correct saying that - apart from the overhead obviously - the workings of this query is pretty much the same as two seperate queries?

Comment: @Michel The result is the same. The query is more fast than two separate queries and slightly slower than one of these two queries. Especially when suitable indices are present. Remember - the most part of execution time is writing altered data to disk.